# Unexpected NumberFormatException while parsing a hex string to an int value

Tags: java, hex

I want to parse an String containing 8 hex-digits (4bytes) but i got an NumberFormatException. What is wrong here?

```
assertThat(Integer.parseInt("FFFF4C6A",16),is(0xFFFF4C6A));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your number represents a number greater than that assignable to an int. Try:

```
Long.parseLong("FFFF4C6A", 16);
```

which gives 4294921322.

From the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-):

> An exception of type `NumberFormatException` is thrown if any of the following situations occurs:
>
> - The first argument is null or is a string of length zero.
> - The radix is either smaller than `Character.MIN_RADIX` or larger than `Character.MAX_RADIX`.
> - Any character of the string is not a digit of the specified radix, …
> - The value represented by the string is not a value of type int.

and it's the 4th case that you're hitting.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the `Integer.parseInt("FFFF4C6A",16)` provided exceeds [Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) which is defined as `public static final int   MAX_VALUE = 0x7fffffff;`

Now, as per the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) for parseInt(...), you would hit a *NumberFormatException* in either of the following cases:

An exception of type *NumberFormatException* is thrown if any of the following situations occurs:

> - The first argument is null or is a string of length zero.
> - The radix is either smaller than Character.MIN_RADIX or larger than Character.MAX_RADIX.
> - Any character of the string is not a digit of the specified radix, except that the first character may be a minus sign '-' ('\u002D') or
>     plus sign '+' ('\u002B') provided that the string is longer than
>     length 1.
> - The value represented by the string is not a value of type int.

In your case, since the String value supplied exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE, you're satisfying the 4th clause for *NumberFormatException*

**Possible Solution:** In order to parse this, use `Long.parseLong(...)` where the MAX_VALUE is defined as `` `public static final long MAX_VALUE = 0x7fffffffffffffffL ``

Answer (score 2):

You've exceeded the range of an integer.

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2147483647
0xFFFF4C6A = 4294921322
```

Parsing it as a `Long` works:

```
Long.parseLong("FFFF4C6A",16)
```

Comment: perhaps 16 instead of `Character.MAX_RADIX` expresses the OP's intention better

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to represent that hex string as an integer (since it is 32 bits), you need to use `BigInteger`:

```
new BigInteger("FFFF4C6A", 16).intValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the assertThat() method, but your hexadecimal number "FFFF4C6A" is to big for an integer.

For example, if you write :

> int number = Integer.parseInt("FFFF4C6A",16)

you'll get the same error.
A correct way to write the code would be :

> double number = Integer.parseInt("FFFF4C6A",16)